# Using IE dev toolbar on a pop up windowed web app

Tags: internet-explorer

We are working on IE only web application that is run as a pop up window - without any toolbars. Is there a way to invoke IE developer's toolbar besides using a button on the IE toolbar, since it is not visible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, I was forced to modify my code, so that I have a server variable read from a config file if we show the toolbar or not. This way when we are in dev or qa we show the toolbar, but in production we hide it.

If someone knows of a better way hopefully they will chime in.

## Edit

Ohh and this doesn't work at all for a modal dialog window.showModalDialog (or if ie supports it window.open(page,"modal=yes") ) and ctrl-n doesn't work either.

Answer (score 36):

Yes. You need to turn off the security option "Allow websites to open windows without address or status bars".

In IE9 the menu option is at (believe it is same in 8):
Go Tools / Internet options / Security / (pick the right zone for your site) / Custom Level
Under "Miscellaneous"
Under "Allow websites to open windows without address or status bars", choose "Disable".

You should now have an address bar in your modal dialogs and be able to hit F12 to open IE developer toolbar.

Comment: If using a VM on a Mac I had to press fn+F12 to get the dev tools to open.

Answer (score 8):

Press CTRL-n while the window is active. It will open the same URL in a non pop-up window, complete with tool bar.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use the IE8 beta/RC, try hitting F12 on the popup.

Answer (score -1):

copy url link of the popup and open in in a separate window or tab