# Not able to open developer tools on a Modal dialog in IE11 on windows 10

Tags: modal-dialog, internet-explorer-11

Not able to open developer tools on a Modal dialog in IE11 on windows 10. Recently I upgraded to Windows10, I have done the attached settings in my IE but still it is not working.

[image: Settings IE11]
[image: Settings IE11]

Comment: You can find the answer for your question in this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908729/debug-a-modal-dialog-showmodaldialog-in-ie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908729/debug-a-modal-dialog-showmodaldialog-in-ie)

Comment: @ThiagoJordan, I tried the above, but still it is not working. I have attached the same screenshots.

Comment: Just as a partial workaround: try intercepting the complete popup link with let's say Fiddler and open it in a normal tab where you can debug it. Is your IE up to date?

Comment: It doesn't work with my application. Still the issues exists. If anyone knows the answer please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to have been answered [elsewhere](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29010779/Not-able-to-open-developer-tools-on-a-Modal-dialog-in-IE11-on-windows-10.html). Interestingly asked by @vijaykandady on the other forum as well around the same date and marked as solved.

Pasting a screenshot of the accepted solution from that forum.

[image: Screenshot of the solution page]

Comment: This was suggested by another user, but it doesn't work for me. It just shows the print screen dialog. (They've since deleted their answer). **Interestingly** this prompted me to open the dev tools in the main window before opening the modal, and when I press F12 I see a dialog:
```The F12 developer tools in the main Internet Explorer window must be closed before opening in this dialogue. 

To close the existing F12 developer tools window and open them here, click OK. Otherwise, click Cancel.
```
on clicking "OK" it closed the main windows dev tools, but doesn't open the modal's.

Comment: @SamHasler Following another discussion. The 2 options shown are: 1) Use Control + Shift + I or 2) Use Microsoft Edge browser. Mind you I personally haven't tried either of these.

Discussion here: https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/ie11-f12-developer-tools-not-show-properly/

Comment: ```CTRL```+```Shift```+```I``` doesn't trigger the "close the dev tools in the main window" dialog the way F12 does. (I have to click on the titlebar for F12 to do this.)
Edge isn't an option, the page is rendering in quirks mode.

Comment: @SamHasler Going back to the earlier suggestion, are you able to manually unpin (click with mouse instead of keyboard shortcut) the F12 window from the main window? Asking as ctrl+P showing print dialog suggests focus is still on the IE window instead of dev tools window. As long as it gets unpinned, the dev tools for modal window should show up there as well.

Comment: As I stated above, if the main window F12 dev tools are open, then pressing F12 on the modal brings up this dialog: https://i.imgur.com/EkIMTeC.png 

On clicking OK the main tools are closed (pinned or unpinned), but no tools open for the modal.

Comment: @Sam Hasler, If I can't find a definitive explanation either way is a work-around an acceptable answer?

Comment: @JonathanChaplin Anything that gets me into the actual F12 dev tools or explains why they don't work will be acceptable but using something like firebug lite or another browser wouldn't.

Comment: worked for me. Ctrl+P undocks the dev tools into a separate window, in that case it does not crash. Apparently it only freezes when it is docked along with browser window.

Answer (score 1):

Open DevTools -> Console in the main window and run the following command:

```
window.showModalDialog = window.open
```

It will force browser to open all modal dialogs in a regular window.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running IE11 with add-ons disabled as this link suggests?

- Right-click on Start
- Left-click on Run
- In the Run dialog type iexplore.exe -extoff then click OK
- This opens IE with ad-ons
  disabled. Close the alert that pops up at bottom, the in the address
  bar enter a website to go to, then try press F12 again to see whether
  it opens properly. If it does, then you could open a normal Internet
  Explorer, and click Tools > Manage Add-ons and disable all you have
  then one by one enable them and test whether Developer Tool still
  works, to figure out which one is causing the issue.

https://www.windows10forums.com/threads/ie11-f12-developer-tools-not-show-properly.10199/

Comment: That's a different issue to do with the tools working properly once opened in the main window. This question is about getting the tools to even open in a modal dialog opened via showModalDialog.

Comment: Yes you're right. However are you running any extensions on IE11? Maybe there's an extension that contributes to the problem?