# Can't we identify the elements present in a Modal window?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, modal-dialog

I've been using Java Robot to handle Modal windows by performing Mouse and Key events on them. But is there a way to actually identify an element and its properties present in a Modal window using some tool?, And what are the alternatives for Robot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of a modal window?

Comment: @Zach You can try this in firefox to get a modal window. Type dt:// in address bar and press enter . You will find a modal window saying that firefox can't handle the protocol 'dt'

Comment: @Zach: I think only IE supports [modal windows](http://javascript.about.com/library/blmodal.htm). They aren't common in public websites, but are used in a number of corporate web apps where the users are known to have IE.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I am stuck in a similar situation.  The F12 doesn't work on the modal window.  And when I tried getting the source through Webdriver, all I get is the frame's code.

Comment: @Ramnath http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420542/using-ie-dev-toolbar-on-a-pop-up-windowed-web-app  See the answer by David Eison